# How to solve a very large set of linear equations that cannot be solved in one go due to ram overflow on a computer?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a set of linear equations for my thesis that looks like:

$$\bigl[C\bigr] \bigl[ \phi \bigr] = \bigl[S\bigr]$$

Very generic, I know. but the problem I am facing is that the matrix $[C]$ has the dimensions of 125,000+ * 125,000+, and the other two matrices are each as long as $[C]$ row-wise.

This is actually for a 3D neutron flux calculator. It has to be able to calculate for geometries larger than 50 * 50 * 50 mesh points, which gives me a $[C]$ matrix of 125,000 * 125,000 dimensions at the minimum. I am running out of RAM (Of course I am, the $[C]$ matrix has 15+ billion points) trying to assign values to these behemoth matrices, let alone inverse and solve the system.

So I am looking for suggestions as to how to solve this type of system. Maybe I can break it down into smaller matrices and do some calculations from there? Give me some pointers please, thanks.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you sure the matrix $C$ is not [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)?

Comment: @Rahul yes, it is sparse. It has 7 or 9 diagonals dependent on the geometry.

Comment: Then you only need to store $9\times125\,000$ entries in memory, not $125\,000^2$! I suggest you start by learning more about working with sparse matrices. Whatever linear algebra software you are using should support sparse matrices; if it doesn't, drop it and find one that does.

Comment: Thanks, this is the type of suggestion I needed. I was looking for a place to start studying and figuring it out rather than a specific solution. I'll start learning about sparse matrices and how to tackle problems like this. Thanks again.